# How to move an image control to a specific X,Y co-ordinate?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I move an image automatically to a specific X,Y position where I touch on the screen? I have tried using `GeneralTransform` but this is not working. What kind of class should I use for moving an image in Windows Phone 8?

This is my code:

```cs
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("2.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
img.MaxHeight=10;
img.MaxWidth = 10;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
GeneralTransform temp = LayoutRoot.TransformToVisual(img);
new Size(img.ActualHeight,img.ActualWidth);
TouchPoint primaryTouchPoint = args.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(null);
Point pt = primaryTouchPoint.Position;
if (primaryTouchPoint.Action == TouchAction.Up)
{
    Point point = temp.Transform(pt);                
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the LayoutRoot is.

If it's a Grid, then you can simply set the left and top margin when you know where the user tapped.

```
img.Margin = new Thickness(pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0);
```

If you're using canvas, you can set the Left and Top properties of canvas

```
Canvas.SetLeft(img, pt.X);
Canvas.SetTop(img, pt.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your panel is canvas you can move image by setting: Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top with your image and touch point